# Javascript not running setInterval when page served from tomcat - works fine from desktop

Tags: javascript, jsp, tomcat

I've been having some weird problems with javascript not running correctly inside jsp pages served from my local development tomcat server. It's weird because if I paste the same source into a text file, save as jsp, and open it from desktop works perfectly.

I've cut everything back to the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
                console.log('interval running...');
                document.getElementById('interval-status').textContent = ('Interval Running...');
            }, 1000);

            console.log('Interval Created: ' + intervalId);
            document.getElementById('interval-status').textContent = ('Interval Created: ' + intervalId);

        </script>

        <span id='interval-status'></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above pasted into a jsp file on desktop and opened with a browser, this page shows "Interval Running...", and the console shows the same. All good!

When this page is served from tomcat (as a jsp file), I get `TypeError: Document.getElementById(...) is null`. Ugh ok, so I move the script below the span, and the page loads successfully. However it only shows "Interval Created: 2", and the console shows the same. The interval doesn't actually execute its callback.

So, questions:

**1)** Why does the script have to be below the span when served from tomcat, but not my desktop?

**2)** Why doesn't the interval run when served via jsp/tomcat? It's possibly related to question 1?

**Edit: It appears to work correctly when loaded through Edge and Chrome. Not Firefox (54.0.1 32bit). Must be browser related...**

Comment: Is your JSP parser doing something weird?  If you take the file as served by your server, and save it to a local file and open it, how does it compare to the original file that works locally?

Comment: Just tried this - copying view-source into a local file and running it has no issues, while the served page doesn't work.

Comment: _Why does the script have to be below the span..._ Obviously because the `span` element doesn't exist in DOM when the above `script` runs. In order to ensure presence of an element you have to listen for `load` event.

Comment: @hindmost ok then to rephrase - why can the script be above the span when run from a local file?

Comment: _why can the script be above the span when run from a local file?_ The cause is the same: `span` element doesn't exist yet at that moment.

Comment: @hindmost I think you misread me - The script works perfectly above the span when run from local.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you described. Perhaps that are specifics of your browser. However your approach is wrong. Code dealing with DOM elements should never be run in-place; it must be wrapped with `onload` listener.

Comment: @hindmost I'm not sure how you can't reproduce it - The code in the question above works in all of Chrome, Firefox and Edge. It only doesn't work when served from tomcat to Firefox. My approach for this [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) isn't relevant because I'm actually using jQuery and the real issue is the setInterval, not the getElement.